# How to create lists within a list of a N dimension python

Tags: python, list

I got a python array as:

```
var=array([[ 0. , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1. ]])
```

then, from the characteristics of this variable, I would like to initialize a new variable (`var1`) which has to be two lists within a single list as:

```
var1=[[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Note that the dimensions of each list into `var1` list has to match that of **var** (in this case 5).

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "from the characteristics of this variable" - are you just looking at the length of the array? Or do you care about its contents?

Comment: you mean something like `var1=[ [0. , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1. ],[ 0. , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1. ]]` ??

Comment: I care about the length of the array which has to match that of var (in this case 5). The content, instead, can be whatever but usually is a single value.

Comment: I do not mean something like var1=[ [0. , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1. ],[ 0. , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1. ]] . I mean: if var=var=array([[ 0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ]]) then var1=[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]. So the length of the two lists in var 1 matches that of var (in this other case is 11). Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
 var1 = [[1 for item in var] for listIndex in range (2)]
```

Note that var1 will contain two separate lists, rather than two references to the same list. If all elements of both lists remain 1, a reference would do as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `np.ones()`.

```
import numpy as np
var = np.array([[ 0. , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1. ]])
var_len = len(var[0])
var1 = [np.ones(var_len), np.ones(var_len)]
print var1
# [array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
var1 = [[1]*len(var),[1]*len(var)]
>>> var1
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

If you need a bigger list (more than two lists in a single list), you could apply a loop using the same idea.

Comment: It works fine unless the fact that I need to run map command to convert my original array (var into a list). Many thanks!